# The package javax.sql.rowset is not accessible

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to implement a `CachedRowSet`.  I'm using VS Code, jdk19, and maven.

In my DBUtil.java file, I have this:

```
package searcher;

import javax.sql.rowset;
import java.sql.*;
```

"*The package javax.sql.rowset is not accessible*" occurs on the import javax line.

settings.json

```
{
  "java.configuration.updateBuildConfiguration": "interactive",
  "java.jdt.ls.java.home": "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-19\\"
}
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>searcher</groupId>
    <artifactId>searcher</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.31</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>13</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running -->
                        <!-- Usage: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>searcher.App</mainClass>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I've tried clean workspace.  I've tried changing pom.xml.

I just tried editing module-info.java and adding requires transitive java.sql.rowset.

What I find really frustrating is that the Explorer panel on the left shows JRE System Library and under java.sql.rowset is javax.sql.Rowset listed.

Comment: Do you really think it's a good idea to use JavaFX 13 together with Java 19?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you just made a capitalization error.

- [`javax.sql.Rowset`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/RowSet.html) (uppercase "R") is an interface in the `javax.sql` package.

  - (of which [`javax.sql.rowset.CachedRowSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/rowset/CachedRowSet.html) is a subinterface).
- [`javax.sql.rowset`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/rowset/package-summary.html) (lowercase "r") is a package.

To import everything in a package, you need to do what you were doing with "`import java.sql.*;`": `import javax.sql.rowset.*;`. But you probably just want to `import javax.sql.rowset.CachedRowSet;`.